# Why I can't calculate time complexity by multiplying?

Tags: time-complexity, nested-loops

I want to get the time complexity of this pseudocode:

```
count = 0;
for (i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) 
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        count++;
```

I thought it was log(n)*log(n), but the answer is log(n). I was told that because i*2 has nonlinear growth, I can't multiply directly.

I am confused why I can't do that: I don't know the rules about when I can multiply when I can't. When I calculate time complexity, I just multiply them when I meet nested loops. How should I calculate it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you got is wrong. The complexity is O().

For a given , the number of iterations of the inner loop is equal to , and  will take the value of each power of 2 that is less than . There are ⌈log<sub>2</sub>⌉ such powers. And so the total number of iterations of the inner loop is the sum of those powers, i.e.

2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + ... + 2<sup>⌈log<sub>2</sub>⌉−1</sup>

This is the sum of the first terms of a [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), and thus equal to:

2<sup>⌈log<sub>2</sub>⌉</sup>−1

This is O().

We can illustrate this by running the script for several values of , notably powers of 2:

```js
function getCount(n) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) 
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
            count++;
    return count;
}

for (let n = 1; n < 70000; n *= 2) {
    let count = getCount(n);
    console.log("For", n, "count is", count);
}
```

As you can see the number of times that `count++` executes is one less than the value of `n`, when `n` is a power of 2.

Comment: I am really appreciate your answer!! I can get your point.But i am still want to know  if nonlinear growth is the reason why i can't multiply directly.Looking forward to your reply,thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't understand your multiplication from the start -- where would the second `log(n)` come from with which you wanted to multiply? The inner loop does not represent a logarithmic complexity, and it is not defined in terms of `n`, but of `i`. If you mean with nonlinear growth, that `i` grows exponentially, then yes, that has an impact. When you make a complexity analysis you have to take into account all aspects. There can be cases where the inner loop depends on `n`, not on `i`, or it may count from `i` to `n`, or ... there are many other possibilities, and they give different results.

Comment: The first log(n) is times,And i make a mistake,i thought j is  0~i ,so it is the same as log(n).Now i know, every i correspond to j,but that is not means i's time equals to j.Thanks your patience and help!

Comment: Sure! It is my pleasure to do that.

Comment: Glad to see it was useful!